Как распределить выполнение программы на разные видеокарты в CUDA C
Например у меня есть 2 массива с которыми нужно проделать некоторые операции и перенести данные в общий массив, при этом у меня в компьютере стоит 2 видеокарты, как сделать так что бы каждая видеокарта работала со своим массивом.

cudaSetDevice.

А в таком случае обе видеокарты будут параллельно нагружены? Заранее спасибо!

Один пример лучше тысячи слов: https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/blob/master/Samples/0_Introduction/simpleP2P/simpleP2P.cu

Спасибо большое!!
